# Python code never reaching a certain part that it should

Tags: python

Hey I am creating a roguelike game with python using Libtcod.  I have code where the game makes random rooms.  It should be making multiple rooms until one crosses and then stops making the rooms.  The problem is it always only creates 1 room.  Here is the hole code:

```
import libtcodpy as libtcod;

SCREEN_WIDTH = 80;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 50;

MAP_WIDTH = 80
MAP_HEIGHT = 45

ROOM_MAX_SIZE = 10
ROOM_MIN_SIZE = 6
MAX_ROOMS = 30

LIMIT_FPS = 20;

color_dark_wall = libtcod.Color(0, 0, 100)
color_dark_ground = libtcod.Color(50, 50, 150)

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, blocked, block_sight = None):
        self.blocked = blocked

        if block_sight is None: block_sight = blocked
        self.block_sight = block_sight

class Rect:
    def __init__(self, x, y , w, h):
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        self.x2 = x + w
        self.y2 = y + h

    def center(self):
        center_x = (self.x1 + self.x2) / 2
        center_y = (self.y1 + self.y2) / 2
        return (center_x, center_y)

    def intersect(self, other):
        return (self.x1 <= other.x2 and self.x2 >= other.x1 and
                self.y1 <= other.y2 and self.y2 >= other.y1)

class Object:
    def __init__(self, x, y, char, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.color = color

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if not map[self.x + dx][self.y + dy].blocked:
            self.x += dx
            self.y += dy

    def draw(self):
        libtcod.console_set_default_foreground(con, self.color)
        libtcod.console_put_char(con, self.x, self.y, self.char, libtcod.BKGND_NONE)

    def clear(self):
        libtcod.console_put_char(con, self.x, self.y, ' ', libtcod.BKGND_NONE)

def create_room(room):
    global map

    for x in range(room.x1 + 1, room.x2):
        for y in range(room.y1 + 1, room.y2):
            map[x][y].blocked = False
            map[x][y].block_sight = False

def create_h_tunnel(x1, x2, y):
    global map

    for x in range(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2) + 1):
        map[x][y].blocked = False
        map[x][y].block_sight = False

def create_v_tunnel(y1, y2, x):
    global map

    print("Hello")

    for y in range(min(y1, y2), max(y1, y2) + 1):
        map[x][y].blocked = False
        map[x][y].block_sight = False


def make_map():
    global map

    map = [[ Tile(True)
        for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT) ]
            for x in range(MAP_WIDTH) ]

    rooms = []
    num_rooms = 0

    for r in range(MAX_ROOMS):
        w = libtcod.random_get_int(0, ROOM_MIN_SIZE, ROOM_MAX_SIZE)
        h = libtcod.random_get_int(0, ROOM_MIN_SIZE, ROOM_MAX_SIZE)
        x = libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, MAP_WIDTH - w - 1)
        y = libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, MAP_HEIGHT - h -1)

    new_room = Rect(x, y, w, h)

    failed = False

    for other_room in rooms:
        if new_room.intersect(other_room):
            failed = True
            break

    if not failed:
        create_room(new_room)

        (new_x, new_y) = new_room.center()

        if num_rooms == 0:
            player.x = new_x
            player.y = new_y

        else:
            (prev_x, prev_y) = rooms[num_rooms-1].center()

            if libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, 1) == 1:
                create_h_tunnel(prev_x, new_x, prev_y)
                create_v_tunnel(prev_y, new_y, new_x)
            else:
                create_v_tunnel(prev_y, new_y, prev_x)
                create_h_tunnel(prev_x, new_x, new_y)

        rooms.append(new_room)
        num_rooms += 1

def render_all():
    global color_dark_wall, color_light_wall
    global color_dark_ground, color_light_ground

    for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        for x in range (MAP_WIDTH):
            wall = map[x][y].block_sight
            if wall:
                libtcod.console_set_char_background(con, x, y, color_dark_wall, libtcod.BKGND_SET)
            else:
                libtcod.console_set_char_background(con, x, y, color_dark_ground, libtcod.BKGND_SET)

    for object in objects:
        object.draw()

    libtcod.console_blit(con, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0)

def handle_keys():
    key = libtcod.console_check_for_keypress()
    if key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ENTER and key.lalt:
        libtcod.console_set_fullscreen(not libtcod.console_is_fullscreen())

    elif key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ESCAPE:
        return True  #exit game

    if libtcod.console_is_key_pressed(libtcod.KEY_UP):
        player.move(0, -1)

    elif libtcod.console_is_key_pressed(libtcod.KEY_DOWN):
        player.move(0, 1)

    elif libtcod.console_is_key_pressed(libtcod.KEY_LEFT):
        player.move(-1, 0)

    elif libtcod.console_is_key_pressed(libtcod.KEY_RIGHT):
        player.move(1, 0)

libtcod.console_set_custom_font('terminal10x10_gs_tc.png', libtcod.FONT_TYPE_GREYSCALE | libtcod.FONT_LAYOUT_TCOD);
libtcod.console_init_root(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'Lets Crawl', False);
libtcod.sys_set_fps(LIMIT_FPS);
con = libtcod.console_new(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

player = Object(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, '@', libtcod.green)
npc = Object(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 5, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, '@', libtcod.yellow)
objects = [npc, player]

#makes the map
make_map()

while not libtcod.console_is_window_closed():

    render_all()


    #libtcod.console_check_for_keypress()

    libtcod.console_flush();

    for object in objects:
        object.clear()

    exit = handle_keys()
    if exit:
        break
```

And here is the make_map() function where I suspect the problem is:

```
def make_map():
    global map

    map = [[ Tile(True)
        for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT) ]
            for x in range(MAP_WIDTH) ]

    rooms = []
    num_rooms = 0

    for r in range(MAX_ROOMS):
        w = libtcod.random_get_int(0, ROOM_MIN_SIZE, ROOM_MAX_SIZE)
        h = libtcod.random_get_int(0, ROOM_MIN_SIZE, ROOM_MAX_SIZE)
        x = libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, MAP_WIDTH - w - 1)
        y = libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, MAP_HEIGHT - h -1)

    new_room = Rect(x, y, w, h)

    failed = False

    for other_room in rooms:
        if new_room.intersect(other_room):
            failed = True
            break

    if not failed:
        create_room(new_room)

        (new_x, new_y) = new_room.center()

        if num_rooms == 0:
            player.x = new_x
            player.y = new_y

        else:
            (prev_x, prev_y) = rooms[num_rooms-1].center()

            if libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, 1) == 1:
                create_h_tunnel(prev_x, new_x, prev_y)
                create_v_tunnel(prev_y, new_y, new_x)
            else:
                create_v_tunnel(prev_y, new_y, prev_x)
                create_h_tunnel(prev_x, new_x, new_y)

        rooms.append(new_room)
        num_rooms += 1
```

After the program creates the room, it adds the room to the list but does it not continue to make rooms?  Or is it that each room created is the same size (even though im passing random numbers) and it creates the first room and then stops?  I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have an indentation error. Looks like everything after the definition of w, h, x and y is supposed to be part of the same for loop, so should be indented to the same level.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks man.  No matter how long I look at my code I never seem to find these errors.  I guess having a second pair of eyes look at it helps a lot.  thanks man